# How to get Platinum on Tougher Blocky in Team Kirby Clash Deluxe

Tags: team-kirby-clash-deluxe

I don't have any gem apples to upgrade my equipment, but i'm level 39 and I'm trying to get all the platinums I can so I can get all the gem apples I can to unlock Landia EX. However, everytime I fight Tougher Blocky, the AI teammates don't attack. They only seem to wander around and whiff all their moves. Is there an ideal set-up for fighting Blocky?

Comment: Before I answer I want to know if you have resolved it